# How can i use vector3 as float variables?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the top of a script i did:

```
public float setRandScaleXMin, setRandScaleXMax;
public float setTandScaleYMin, setTandScaleYMax;
public float setTandScaleZMin, setRandScaleZMax;
```

But this will create 6 lines.
What i want to do is instead in the inspector:

```
setRandScaleXMin
setRandScaleXMax
setRandScaleYMin
setRandScaleYMax
setRandScaleZMin
setRandScaleZMax
```

To do that they will show in the inspector each two vars in one line:

```
setRandScaleXMin 10 setRandScaleXMax 111
setRandScaleYMin 12 setRandScaleYMax 22
setRandScaleZMin 11 setRandScaleZMax 15
```

Instead 6 lines only 3 lines.

Then i'm using it like this:

```
        float randScaleX = Random.Range(setRandScaleXMin, setRandScaleXMax);
        float randScaleY = Random.Range(setTandScaleYMin, setTandScaleYMax);
        float randScaleZ = Random.Range(setTandScaleYMax, setRandScaleZMax);
```

And

```
objInstance = Instantiate(objectToInstantiate, new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ), Quaternion.identity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only feel like I vaguely understand what you are trying to say so please forgive me if I am wrong, but you are looking for minimum and maximum X, Y, and Z. Instead of having six lines in an inspector window, you can have two:

```
public Vector3 MinRandScale;
public Vector3 MaxRandScale;
```

RandScaleMin represents the minimum X, Y, and Z limits of your random scale and RandScaleMax represents the maximum X, Y, and Z limits of your random scale.
[image]

**Edit To Show How To Use With Random.Range():**

`Random.Range` takes two values: A minimum bound and a maximum bound. So you simply do the following to get a Vector3 with randomized components:

```
var randX = Random.Range(MinRandScale.x, MaxRandScale.x);
var randY = Random.Range(MinRandScale.y, MaxRandScale.y);
var randZ = Random.Range(MinRandScale.z, MaxRandScale.z);
var randVector3 = new Vector3(randX, randY, randZ);
```

Comment: And how do i use it in the Random.Range and the Instantiate ?  It will not accept Vector3 and not 3 parameters only 2.

Comment: I edited my question with how i used the Random.Range and how i used the Instantiate before changing it to Vector3.

Comment: I edited my question to include how to use Random.Range, but you seem to have edited yours first. So is your problem now solved? Can you  mark this as answered?